# How to create a dichotomous variable?

Tags: r

I would like to create a dichotomous variable about corruption defining:

0 = every country with a value inferior or equal to 50 (low level of corruption),

1 = every country with a value superior or equal to 50 (high level of corruption)

I don't know if i'm doing right

This is my desk:

My variable is corruption, so

```
cpi_nueva$corruption <- ifelse(cpi_nueva$corruption >= 50, "less corruption", "more corruption" )
```

Comment: If you just need 0, 1 values, you can use `+(cpi_nueva$corruption >= 50)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: This is just about basic R. I removed inadequate tags

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What's the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution, where:

- `cpi_nueva`: is your data.frame
- `corruption`: is the numeric variable in `cpi_nueva`
- `corruption_cat`: is the dichotomous that will be created

### Libraries

`library(tidyverse)`

### Code

```
cpi_nueva %>% 
   mutate(
      corruption_cat  = if_else(corruption >= 50,"less corruption","high corruption")
   )
```